# How to send (and receive) streaming images to server

Tags: flutter, dart, http, asynchronous, streaming

I am using Flutter (3.7.11) with the camera package.
the `CameraController` has a method `startingImageStream` which I want to utilise to send the images to a backend server for processing and back.
What is the best approach here?

1. Can I use the async http package for that purpose (as the method `startingImageStream` requires a non-async callback)?
2. Do I have to use synchronous http requests?